# python ecdsa get private and public key

Tags: python, cryptography, ecdsa

This question may seem simple for those who know the library. How do I get the actual value of the private and public keys? I have:

```
private_key = SigningKey.generate(SECP256k1)
public_key = private_key.get_verifying_key()
print("private_key:")
print(private_key)
print("public_key:")
print(public_key)
```

And it prints:

> > > > generate_keys() private_key:  public_key:
> > > >         VerifyingKey.from_string(b'\x029q\xfd\xe9\x1dL\xc0\xab\xb1\xd2GG\xef8\xcb\x89\xce\xbb\xa8\x10*\xfa\xda\x0c\x92\x12\xa5\xa0\x81\xef\x07\x9e',
> > > >         SECP256k1, sha1) (,
> > > >         VerifyingKey.from_string(b'\x029q\xfd\xe9\x1dL\xc0\xab\xb1\xd2GG\xef8\xcb\x89\xce\xbb\xa8\x10*\xfa\xda\x0c\x92\x12\xa5\xa0\x81\xef\x07\x9e',
> > > >         SECP256k1, sha1))

I need the private_key and public_key real values. How do I get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have generated the private and public keys correctly. You now have class instances. These instances are not necessarily printing the way you expect - I think that is your only issue.

If you want to see PEM format, you should do this:

```
private_key = SigningKey.generate(SECP256k1)
public_key = private_key.get_verifying_key()
print("private_key:")
print(private_key.to_pem())
print("public_key:")
print(public_key.to_pem())
```

For DER format, use *to_der()*.  For raw bytes, use *to_string()*.

If you are communicating a key to someone, to a wallet, to openssl, etc, you probably want PEM format.